# Matrix of operator of reflection relatively some hyperplane

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, reflection

Assume we have a subspace $W$of some Euclid space $V$.

Consider an operator of reflection relatively some hyperplane: $W$ is a hyperplane, if $\dim W = \dim V - 1$.

How does its matrix look like, i.e what are the elements of this matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that the matrix $A$ is
$$A = P^{-1} B P$$
where $B$ is the identity matrix modified by replacing one of the diagonal terms by $-1$.

Comment: Can you please clarify your answer, since I'm having trouble with understanding some of the concepts?

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: @Welez  Could you please clarify your question, and what you have tried (and do so as an edit to your post).

Comment: @amWhy I edited the question and posted my thoughts as an answer below. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 1):

I have a mapping $T: R^n \to R^n$ and I want it to represent a reflection over some $k$ coordinate.

Initially, we have an identity matrix $E$, which columns represent a standard basis of $R^n$.

I have some vector $\vec{v} = (c_1, c_2, \dotso, c_k, \dotso, c_n)$. I want to flip it over $k$-axis.

Consider some point $p = (p_1, p_2, \dotso, p_k, \dotso, p_n)$.

If I refelct it over $k$-axis the $k$-th will become $-p_k$.

Essentially in order to represent reflection we just need to flip the sign of $k$-th coordinate. Probably the easiest way to see this is to draw some points in $R^2$ and try to reflect it over some axis.

Also, I know that there exist some matrix $A$, such that for all $v \in V \ T(v) = A \cdot v$ and its columns nothing but $T(e_i)$.

So far, I have $T
    \begin{bmatrix}
           c_{1} \\
           \vdots \\
           c_{k} \\
           \vdots \\
           c_n
         \end{bmatrix}
  =  \begin{bmatrix}
           c_{1} \\
           \vdots \\
           -c_{k} \\
           \vdots \\
           c_n
         \end{bmatrix}
  $.

Finally, to construct matrix $A$, have to calculate $T(e_i) \ \forall i$. The only basis vector, which has a non-zero entry on the $k$-th coordinate is located at the $k$-th column of an identity matrix.

I end up with an identity matrix with $-1$ instead of $1$ on the column which represents the axis over which I want to perform reflection.

Comment: It is correct. The next step is that upon changing the order of the basis vectors, the mapping becomes the reflection over the first coordinate, and the matrix becomes $B=\text{diag}(-1, 1, \cdots, 1)$. The matrix $A$ can be written $A = Q B Q^T$, where the columns of the matrix $Q$ are the new basis vectors. We have $Q^T = Q^{-1}$ (orthogonal matrix), and the same thing can be done for any reflection by choosing an orthonormal basis which first vector is orthogonal to the stable hyperplane and the other vectors are in this  hyperplane.